# Does Python float function automatically recognize numbers?

Tags: python

So here is a simple problem input:
The first line contains an integer, N, the number of students.
The  2N subsequent lines describe each student over  lines.
The first line contains a student's name.
The second line contains their grade.
and code:

```
l = []
second_lowest_names = []
scores = set()

for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())
    l.append([name, score])
    scores.add(score)
        
second_lowest = sorted(scores)[1]

for name, score in l:
    if score == second_lowest:
        second_lowest_names.append(name)

for name in sorted(second_lowest_names):
    print(name, end='\n')
```

I'm just a bit confused of how the float() function only takes the numbers but not the names as input
here's a sample input

```
5
Harry
37.21
Berry
37.21
Tina
37.2
Akriti
41
Harsh
39
```

Comment: You only *called* `float` on the lines that represented numbers. You didn't call it on the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, you call `input()` twice. Each time you get a single line of the input, so the two values corresponding to the student are both read in a single pass of the loop:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
    name = input()              # get the name
    score = float(input())      # get the score, and convert it to a number
```

Only the second input line, which represents the student's score, gets passed to `float`. If you passed the student's name (from the previous line) to `float`, you'd get an exception unless the student had a very unconventional name (like `'Nan'` or  `'Inf'`).

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what float does? It's an abbreviation for [floating point number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic), which is a way of representing numbers in computers that can have fractional portions after the decimal point. Whenever you call input(), python always receives what you typed as a string, which means a sequence of characters.

Strings have no direct numeric meaning in the computer in the way that floats do. The string "41" to the computer is not the meaningful number that you or I would immediately interpret it as. To the computer, it is just two characters in order, the first of which happens to be the "4" character and the second of which happens to be the "1" character - nothing more, nothing less. The quotes in python indicate strings. If you were to evaluate "41"+"1" you would get "411". You could even evaluate "41" + "hello" to get "41hello". These are all just strings.

Calling float("41") takes the string and tries to evaluate it into an floating point number which the computer interprets as an actual number and not simply a sequence of characters. The sum of two floating point values such as 41.0 + 1.0 evaluates to 42.0 as you would expect.

Since a student's name is not meant to represent a number, you should not try to call float() on it as it doesn't make any sense to do so. Float will most likely fail to produce a numeric interpretation unless the name was one of a few special strings like "nan" (not a number) or "inf" (infinity). If the name did happen to be one of these strings, you wouldn't want this translation anyways.

This is why float is called on the numeric entities and not on the names in the code.

Another similar thing besides float() is int(), which is an abbreviation of integer. Both  floats and ints are actual numeric representations. The difference essentially is that integers are restricted to be whole numbers (positive, negative, or zero), whereas floating point values can have fractional numbers after the decimal point. They are different ways of expressing numbers within a computer, each suited to different situations.